# best way to store data in wpf application

Tags: wpf, storing-data

i just want to know about the best way to store sensitive and secured data in wpf application that will not appear inside the exe file like databases and will store data and retrieve it when program start up again

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place for discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: sorry it's not a discussion as you understand 
it's a question that i really need it's answer

Comment: Are you accepting the data through the user interface or are you building the application with the 'sensitive' data?

Comment: Have a look at this: [Store sensitive information inside keepass database from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680352/store-sensitive-information-inside-keepass-database-from-c)

Comment: @Devendra D. Chavan it's not a password but tons of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the latest comment, it seems that you need to encrypt user input data. Depending on the size of the data you could go with [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) or [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx). You can have a look at [SQL Server 2008 R2 CE encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237941%28SQL.80%29.aspx) or [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express encryption](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/).

If you are not looking at databases, then you could have a look at [file based encryption](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/fileencryptdecrypt.aspx) using the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace.

Higher levels of security are available in the enterprise version of [SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/R2-editions.aspx). More information on encryption levels in SQL Server 2008 can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

Note that encryption of the database (depending on the algorithm used) can [negatively affect the performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384409/sql-based-encryption-performance).